# use a variable in another function in javascipt

Tags: javascript, html, validation, variables

I have an idea, but need some instruction to do it.

I want to use in variable in function then use it in another function.
Let me explain:

```
myfunction() {

....

var explain = "yes";

}


myfunction2() {

if ( explain == "yes") {

...
}
}
```

Comment: Either broaden its scope or pass it in.

Comment: why not pass `explain` as one parameter of `myfunction2`?

Answer (score 1):

define explain outside of myFunction(), here's an example:

```
var explain = "yes";

myfunction() {

....

}

myfunction2() {

if ( explain == "yes") {

... } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices: either make the variable global (or move it up to the lowest scope accessible by both functions) or pass it as an argument to the second function.

Option 1:

```
var explain;
function myfunction() {
    explain = "yes";
}
function myfunction2() {
    if ( explain == "yes") {
       //...
    }
}
myfunction();
myfunction2();
```

Option 2:

```
function myfunction() {
    var explain = "yes";
    myfunction2(explain);
}
function myfunction2(explain) {
    if ( explain == "yes") {
       //...
    }
}
myfunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make the variable in one function and call it in other function like the following:

```js
function myfunction() {
  window.value = 'yes'; //declaring global variable by window object
}

function myfunction2() {
  console.log(window.value); //accessing global variable from other function  
  if (window.value == 'yes') {
    console.log('Run')
  }
}
myfunction();
myfunction2();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possibilities:
**1.** **Declare it as global.**

```js
var explain;

function myfunction() {
    explain = "yes";
}

function myfunction2() {
    if ( explain == "yes") {
         console.log('yes');
    }
}

myfunction();
myfunction2();
```

**2.**  **Use the variable as return and function-parameter.**

```js
function myfunction3() {
    let explain2 = "yes";
     return explain2;
}

function myfunction4(explain2) {
    if ( explain2 == "yes") {
         console.log('yes');
    }
}

let explain2 = myfunction3();
myfunction4(explain2);
```